# magento2 remove the category id from url?

Tags: category, magento-2.2.5

In magento2 click on category, that category url look like this www.example.com/catalog/category/view/s/hook-and-loop-brands/id/71/

how can i remove the category id and category path in url?

Comment: have you followed this way, check [link](https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-configure-magento-2-seo-friendly-urls.html)

Comment: or do you want to remove just id from above URL  and not fully SEO URL  ?

Comment: actually the url looking like www.example.com/hook-and-loop-brands/
but in my case url having tha catalog/category/view/s/hook-and-loop-brands/id/71 i think its wrong..how can can i solve this

Comment: did you check above link ?

Comment: yes,checked the above link and all settings are same but url have the id

Comment: ok, and how pproduct url is being generated ? are they also not SEO friendly ?

Comment: product urls also look like this 
www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/2375/s/duragrip-brand-hook-and-loop-coins/category/24/

Comment: I think you need to regenerate URL. can you try this module to regenerate URLs https://github.com/Iazel/magento2-regenurl ?

Comment: Note: please take full DB backup before  installing this module.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution to this problem.

For me, I found /category/id appearing at the end of some product url's.  It turned out this was because I had the same product across multiple stores (which is fine), but the url under 'search engine optimisation' needed to be set within the specific store scope on each product and not just the products default scope.

On a product with this issue:

- cope the desired url fromSearch engine optimisation
- change scope to the store
- paste in search engine optimisation
- tick to create a URL rewrite
- Save

Answer (score -1):

You can try setting use category path for product url to no. You will find this option here:

Admin - System – Configuration – Catalog – Catalog - Search Engine Optimisations – selecting No in Use Categories Path for Product URL

After that try flushing cache and reindexing

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Tried this one but again the same issue